# How to attach two jquery functions to window.load event

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I try to load an iframe using SRC values generated dynamically from the previous page.
On the same page, I have a loader gif div that disappears on window load event. I created the effect using jquery.
The iframe loads its content from an external domain, but I prefer the SRC value be hidden from the left bottom corner while the http request is running. And yes, I'm aware that the URL will be visible to anybody who cares to examine the DOM .
Now to the problem proper. I have tried to include the new function in different configurations using both document. ready and window.load. The iframe never loads on the initial page load. But if I refresh the page, it comes up nice, a couple of mini-seconds after the loader gif div disappears.
Please, can anybody look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.
Here's the jquery code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 var src2=<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION[src]); ?>;

 $(window).on("load", function() {
     $('#loading').hide();
     $('#sample').attr( 'src' , src2);
  });

</script>
```

And here's the iframe HTML snippet:

```
  <iframe id="sample" src="javascript:;" title="" width="$width" style="height: 725px;" scrolling="$scrolling" frameborder="$frameborder" marginheight="$marginheight">
     <a href="$src" target="_blank">$src</a>
  </iframe>
```

Thanks...

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question? What are the two jQuery functions you're trying to attach?

Comment: If you look at the iframe in the DOM inspector, do you see the updated `src`?

Comment: Thank you Barmar for dropping in. Maybe my header was no good. In the jquery snippet I posted, the two functions I need to work are $('#loading').hide(); and $('#sample').attr( 'src' , src2); for the loader gif div and my iframe respectively.

Comment: Those are just two statements in the one `function() { ...}` function. There's no limit to the number of things you can do in there.

Comment: And no, on first page load, the SRC value is empty. But on refresh, the SRC value gets loaded into the iframe and so the iframe loads up.

Comment: Are you sure `src2` is being set correctly? Do you see the correct value in the debugger?

Comment: Yeah, like I said, I've tried different code configurations before getting here. I tried to declare each statement in its own function() {..} block by attaching each of them to window.load separately. Not that the result was any better by the way

Comment: I still suspect the problem is with setting the JS variable from the PHP session variable, not setting the `src`.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But the variable assignment seems to be alright from the debugger. I'm able to print the JavaScript src2 variable after declaring it. Maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `$('#sample').attr( 'src' , src2);`. Examine the variable when it stops. Then single-step over the call, and see whether the `src` has changed in the DOM inspector.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that and get back

Comment: doesnt look to be a jquery problem. as a workaround, try by removing the initial src attribute on iframe element and setting src attribute inside the setTimeout function - like `setTimeout(function(){$('#sample').attr( 'src' , src2);},10);`

Comment: Do `width="$width"` etc. all work? I'm unfamiliar with this notation, if those are all PHP-vars, shouldn't they be inserted like this: `width="<?php $width;?>" ... href="<?php $src;?>"` ?